# How to Create Tab bar programmatically from second viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tabbar

I am developing an application which contains a login page. The first page should be a login page (with a view controller). Once the user has logged in I am going to show another view from that I need to show a tab bar, when the user logs out the same login screen has to be shown. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you create `TabbarController` in your `AppDelegete` class.when user login successfully then you set `Appdelegete` `TabbarController` to `RootViewController` of your window.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.tabBarController];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this type of project but i have made custom tabbar as requirement. After login user have to go to profile page then i use 2nd method but before checking the user has loggedin or not by this 1st method-

```
if([AppHelper userDefaultsForKey:@"user_id"].length>0)
    {
        [[AppDelegate getAppdelegate] createTabBar];
    }
```

then you should you this -

```
-(void)createTabBar
{

    self.tabBarController=[[RXCustomTabBar alloc] init]; 
    self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;   

    Home *homeObj =  [[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *tab1Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeObj];     

    ChatList *chatListObj = [[ChatList alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatList" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *tab2Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chatListObj];


    Settings *settingObj = [[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *tab3Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingObj];  

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: tab1Controller, tab2Controller,tab3Controller, nil];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    [self.tabBarController selectTab:0];

    self.window.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.tabBarController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [self.window addSubview: self.tabBarController.view];


}
```

After this if you have any problem I will be here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would present the log in screen via a modal view. In this case you can implement the tab bar in interface builder for the first view.